# SQL - Create view with one column from two table depending on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a view with one column from two table ... As you will show in the next image.
The squares are table and the rounded corner square is the view and the condition between them.[image]

How to apply this condition to create that view ?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression like

```
create view myview as
select 
    case when (b.Embossied is not null or b.Embossied <> 0)
    then b.Embossied else b1.UniversityId end as alias_name
from Badge b join Badgeldw b1 on b.Embossied = b1.UniversityId;
```

Comment: col1 and col2 for what ?

Comment: @Hansy, those are example column. I don't know what's your actual query but you should be able to get that from this sample

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I need just a embossed or universtyId depending on the written condition in the image

Comment: Thanks again, I had ask you that question because its take a long time to excute, and doesn't get a value

Comment: @Hansy, that's a separate issue and so post it as question separately. you can link this one